# Deriving 2D Coordinate Rotation Formula

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to write out the steps in code for deriving the [2D coordinate rotation formula](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/2drota.htm) so I can understand it.

```
x = radius * cos(angle)
y = radius * sin(angle)
x1 = radius * cos(angle + -rotation)
y1 = radius * sin(angle +  rotation)
```

So,

```
x1 = radius * cos(angle) * cos(rotation) – radius * sin(angle) * sin(rotation)
y1 = radius * sin(angle) * cos(rotation) + radius * cos(angle) * sin(rotation)
```

Therefore,

```
x1 = cos(rotation) * x – sin(rotation) * y
y1 = cos(rotation) * y + sin(rotation) * x
```

I hate to post a question just asking "Is this right?", but is this right? In particular, I'm unsure if I'm correctly representing the `w` (as listed in the link) in the first `x1` and `y1` assignment, and it's expansion. And no, this isn't homework. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Though that site seems a bit intimidating, especially to ask them to check my plus and minus signs.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you look at the rotation this way. What is the coordinates of the rotated $\hat{x}=(1,0)$ axis? From trigonometry you will find it as $X=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. Now what is the coordinates of the rotated $\hat{y}=(0,1)$ axis? Similarly from trig you get $Y=(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$

A general vector $\vec{v}=(A,B)=A \hat{x}+B \hat{y}$ is rotated by rotating the unit vectors $V = A*(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) + B(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ or re-arranged

$$ V = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix} $$

So the rotation matrix is $${\rm Rot}(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's okay, just a minor detail in the initial formulation (the first four lines):

```
x1 = radius * cos(angle + -rotation)
```

Should be:

```
x1 = radius * cos(angle + rotation)
```

(No minus sign, the angle is added in both cases)

By the way, I can understand your doubts. The link you posted first names the rotation angle `w` and then `f`. They should have stuck with `w` or given it a significant name like you did

Comment: Thanks. But without the minus sign, wouldn't the first expansion for x1 also lack one--or is that just a consequence of finding the x value?

Comment: All other equations are ok, it's as if the minus were just a typo and was not considered in the expansions

Comment: @Marcus: The minus sign in your first equation for $x1$ comes from the property of the cosine. The cosine of the sum of two angles is given by the formula $$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta.$$ For sine the corresponding formula reads $$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta.$$ This explains the difference in sign.